Replace part of string with corresponding project number column in SQL Server 2012
I am on SQL Server 2012 and need update part of the path column string with corresponding project number column. Users dont follow the naming convention that is required in the project number column which is XXX.XXXX.XXX. People enter XXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXX or things like XXXX or XXXXXXXabc, XXX.XXXX, etc.
There is quite a bit of variety and i will try to include most if not all the version people have done for file path.
Data



WBS1
File Path




122.1573.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1221573 RETRACEMENT LOT 3 79-25-32.pdf


099.0506.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\99506pos.PDF


099.0281.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\990281(2014-04-04)Hy-Vee Topo.pdf


100.0574.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1000574d.pdf


101.0543.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1010543(sh.1)alta.PDF


107.0848.01B
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1070848B-d.PDF


108.0050.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\108.0050 final plat-79-23-15.pdf



Data - what it should look like:



WBS1
File Path




122.1573.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\122.1573.01 RETRACEMENT LOT 3 79-25-32.pdf


099.0506.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\099.050601pos.PDF


099.0281.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\099.0281.01(2014-04-04)Hy-Vee Topo.pdf


100.0574.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\100.0574.01d.pdf


101.0543.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\101.0543.01(sh.1)alta.PDF


107.0848.01B
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\107.0848.01B-d.PDF


108.0050.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\108.0050.01 final plat-79-23-15.pdf




While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

This feels like an XY Problem; perhaps the application that is saving these files should have 2 input fields; a project number (with formatting validation) and a file name. Then the application saves the file,and stores the data to the databas, with the appropriate name.

SQL Server 2012 has been fully end of life for more than 2 years now. That means it hasn't had any updates in that time... not even critical security patches! It dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it, and upgrading to a supported version is job 1 here.

I understand those users, this naming schema, and i use the words loosely, is awful. Why do you care what the name of file is, if you already have WBS1?

I think we can do this by finding the index of the good part of the filename (suffix). We can then construct a new FilePath using the first 31 chrs + WBS1 + the filename suffix. This solution assumes the first non-numeric non-period chr of the filename starts the suffix. I also assume the first 31 chrs of the FilePath is always the same.
WITH CTE AS
(  
--Find the position of the First Non-Numeric non-period chr in the File name
SELECT *,  
      PATINDEX ( '%[^.0-9]%' , substring(FilePath,31,12)) as FirstNonNumericFileChr
           
FROM project
),Suffix as 
(  
--Calculate the suffix start within FilePath
SELECT *, 
       substring(FilePath,31,FirstNonNumericFileChr-1) as PartToReplaceWithNumericWBS1, 30+FirstNonNumericFileChr as SuffixStart
FROM CTE
),final as 
(  
--Use SuffixStart to construct a new FilePath
SELECT *,  
       substring(FilePath,1,31) 
       + substring(WBS1,1,11) 
       + substring(FilePath,SuffixStart, len(FilePath) - SuffixStart +1) as NewFilePath
FROM Suffix
)
UPDATE final
SET FilePath=NewFilePath

fiddle

this works great for except i was getting an extra number ex 108.0050.01 was 1108.0050.01 in the final path. i adjusted the substring(FilePath,1,31) to substring(FilePath,1,30) .

i did run into one issue - the resulting filepath is missing the '.' before pdf if the filepath looks  anything like '/107111.pdf'. See fiddle i have added an example.
https://dbfiddle.uk/VlYzKRNo

@Dave92 We can use a case expression to handle that scenario https://dbfiddle.uk/CrPB_svY

Here is a couple of solutions. First is based on tokenization via SQL Server's XML and XQuery. Second is more traditional based on string parsing.
Both methods are totally dynamic regardless of how many parts has fully qualified file path. I added extra path part to the row #6.
Method #1 notable points:

1st CROSS APPLY is tokenizing filePath column value as XML.
2nd CROSS APPLY is getting file name only from the last token.
3rd CROSS APPLY is getting the first not-numeric, not-period, not-hyphen character position in the file name.
The Result column is composed by concatenating first last() - 1 = 3 tokens, plus
WBS1 column, and the trailing part of the file name.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, WBS1 VARCHAR(20), FilePath VARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO @tbl (WBS1, FilePath) VALUES
('122.1573.01', 'P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1221573 RETRACEMENT LOT 3 79-25-32.pdf'),
('099.0506.01', 'P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\99506pos.PDF'),
('099.0281.01', 'P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\990281(2014-04-04)Hy-Vee Topo.pdf'),
('100.0574.01', 'P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1000574d.pdf'),
('101.0543.01', 'P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1010543(sh.1)alta.PDF'),
('107.0848.01B','P:\Survey\abc\Survey pdf Drawings\1070848B-d.PDF'),
('108.0050.01', 'P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\108.0050 final plat-79-23-15.pdf');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '\';

-- Method #1
SELECT *
    , REPLACE(x.query('for $x in /root/r[position() lt last()]/text()
        return concat($x, sql:variable("@separator"))
    ').value('.', 'varchar(256)'), '\ ', '\') + 
    WBS1 + SUBSTRING(t2.fileName, charPos, 256) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(FilePath, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT x.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)')) AS t2(fileName)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX ('%[^.0-9][^-]%', fileName)) AS t3(charPos);

-- Method #2
SELECT * 
    , STUFF(FilePath, lastBackSlash + 1, charPos - 1, WBS1) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEN(FilePath) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(FilePath)) + 1) AS t1(lastBackSlash)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX ('%[^.0-9][^-]%' , SUBSTRING(FilePath, lastBackSlash + 1, 256))) AS t3(charPos);

Output



id
WBS1
FilePath
Result




1
122.1573.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1221573 RETRACEMENT LOT 3 79-25-32.pdf
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\122.1573.01 RETRACEMENT LOT 3 79-25-32.pdf


2
099.0506.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\99506pos.PDF
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\099.0506.01pos.PDF


3
099.0281.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\990281(2014-04-04)Hy-Vee Topo.pdf
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\099.0281.01(2014-04-04)Hy-Vee Topo.pdf


4
100.0574.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1000574d.pdf
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\100.0574.01d.pdf


5
101.0543.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\1010543(sh.1)alta.PDF
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\101.0543.01(sh.1)alta.PDF


6
107.0848.01B
P:\Survey\abc\Survey pdf Drawings\1070848B-d.PDF
P:\Survey\abc\Survey pdf Drawings\107.0848.01B-d.PDF


7
108.0050.01
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\108.0050 final plat-79-23-15.pdf
P:\Survey\Survey pdf Drawings\108.0050.01 final plat-79-23-15.pdf



